# Get grand total by column

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I want to calculate the grand total of a given measure in MDX by a column dimension (time dimension)

This is my MDX code:

```
SUM(
([DIM_TIME].[PERIOD]), 
[Measures].[VALUE]
)
```

Basically, this is what I want to get :

[image: Expected output]

But this is what I get:

[image: Actual output]

Thanks for any possible help

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the sample query

```
with member 
[Measures].[Internet Sales AmountTotal]
as
case when [Product].[Category].currentmember is  [Product].[Category].defaultmember then null
else ([Product].[Category].defaultmember,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
end

select
({[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012],[Date].[Calendar Year].&[2013]},
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],[Measures].[Internet Sales AmountTotal]})
on columns,
{[Product].[Category].members}
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]